# MVC 5 view still render required field

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Initially I have two required date time properties in my model. The client side validation works fine for them. But when i comment out the required DataAnnotation on one of the property, MVC view still generating data-val=true, ect... How to i fix this so that mvc view is rendering field is not required.

I've try $('#endDate').rules('remove', 'required') 
but it still checking required field.

Model:

```
public class mymodel{
  ...
  [Required]
  public Datetime startDate { get; set;}

  //[Required]
  public Datetime endDate {get; set}
}
```

View:

```
@Html.LabelFor(model => mode.endDate ....)
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.endDate, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", id="endDate" } })
```

View Render

```
<input class="form-control text-box single-line hasDatepicker input-validation-error" data-val="true" data-val-date="The field endDate must be a date." data-val-required="The endDate field is required." id="endDate" ....>
<span class="text-danger field-validation-error" ....> 
    <span for="endDate" class> The endDate field is required.</span> 
</span>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Properties with non-nullable types (such as `DateTime`) are inherently required, with or without the `Required` attribute, because they must have *some* value. To make it optional, you must use a nullable `DateTime`:

```
public DateTime? endDate { get; set; }
```